# Multiple Task Stacks after Update from Google Play Store

Tags: android

I have an android app which is experiencing a bug after updating to a new version from the google play store. This bug only occurs on certain devices. On some devices (like my Nexus4) I don't see the bug. So let me explain the problem on devices that don't work.

For simplicity, let's assume my app has 2 activities, ActivityA and ActivityB. Let's assume ActivityA is the launch activity. Let's also assume there is a button on ActivityA that creates a new Intent to ActivityB (while keeping ActivityA in the task stack, so clicking the "back" button returns to ActivityA).

On certain devices, I noticed that after updating to a new version from the google play store, the app seems to launch a new version of itself (or a new task stack, not sure how to determine exactly what's happening).

My intention is to return a user to where they left off after an update. So if they were on ActivityB and they click the app icon, I want them to return to ActivityB (this happens with no intervention on my Nexus4, but doesn't seem to occur on other devices).

To deal with this issue, I put logic in my launch activity to go the activity the user was last using. I accomplish this by storing a variable in SharedPreferences on each activity's onStart() method. In the launch activity's OnCreate() method, I check to see if this SharedPreference variable is set, and if so, check if it's set to something other then the launch activity. If it's different, I create a new Intent to the activity referenced in the SharedPreference, and start that activity.

The problem I'm experiencing is that (on certain devices) it appears to launch a separate task stack when I do this. Here's what I see:

1. User starts app (launches ActivityA)
2. User clicks button (launches ActivityB)
3. OnStart() of ActivityB stores "ActivityB" in the SharedPreferences
4. User updates app to newest version on google play store (clicks the google play store icon, selects "My Apps", and clicks "Update All")
5. User clicks app icon shortcut from home screen on phone
6. Launch activity detects SharedPreference was set to ActivityB, so it creates a new Intent for ActivityB (this is the first thing the user sees)
7. User clicks back button and sees ActivityA
8. User clicks back button and sees ActivityB **
9. User clicks back button and sees ActivityA
10. User clicks back button and sees android home screen (app is shut down)

** here is where I would expect to see the android home screen, but it appears another another version of the app, or another task stack is still running.

How can I make sure there are no other tasks running after updating to a new version from the google play store?

Comment: Hard to tell unless you show relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by setting:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

on my activities in the manifest.